# expected value of a random variable and its square

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that X is a random variable with possible values 0,1 and 2. Find a formula for P(X = k) in terms of EX
and E(X^2
) for k = 0,1,2

Note: E(X) refers to the expected value of a random variable

Do I start with the definition of expected values?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Because there are $3$ possible values of $X$, and one of those values is $0$, you end up with two equations with two unknowns $P(X=1)$ and $P(X=2)$.  You then find $P(X=0)$ from $1-P(X=1)-P(X=2)$.  To wit:

$$P(X=1) + 2 P(X=2) = E(X)$$
$$P(X=1)+4 P(X=2) = E(X^2)$$

Solve for the $P$'s.

Comment: (+1) yes, this reduces things to a $2\times2$ matrix equation.

Answer (score 2):

You can write
$$
\mathrm{E}(X)=\sum_{k=0}^2kP(X=k)
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{E}(X^2)=\sum_{k=0}^2k^2P(X=k)
$$
The one that may not be apparent is the one for $\mathrm{E}(1)=1$:
$$
\mathrm{E}(1)=\sum_{k=0}^21\,P(X=k)
$$
Then you can write these as the matrix equation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
0&1&2\\
0&1&4
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
P(X=0)\\
P(X=1)\\
P(X=2)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\mathrm{E}(X)\\
\mathrm{E}(X^2)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Works well in general.